# JavaScript Button not functioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome Extension that allows the user to create a to-do list.  The user is able to add and check off tasks.  I added a delete button, but the delete button won't function.  When I click the delete button, nothing happens.

```js
$(() => {
  $('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      const newTask = $(this).val();
      if (newTask) {
        var li = $("<li><input type='checkbox' id='newtasklist' class='right-margin' <label>" + newTask + "</label> <button type='button' class='deletetask'>Delete</button> </li>");
        $('#tasksUL').append(li);
        $(this).val("");
      }
    }
  });
  $('body').on('click', ':checkbox', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected');
  });
  $('.deletetask').on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="newtask" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New Task" id="newtask">
<ul id="tasksUL">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dynamically creating the button in your JS file. Add the on click event listener to the document, then filter for the delete task class.

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".deletetask", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

This should replace your current .deletetask event listener.

Comment: In the code you provided, your event listener is assigned before the delete button is even created, which is why nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working as expected is because that class `deletetask` is being generated dynamically by your JS. The existing event listener isn't attached to the dynamically created class, so it never knows that the class is clicked. You need your event listener to listen from somewhere above that class in the DOM. There are a few different ways to deal with this:

*(As mentioned by another user)*

```
$(document).on('click', '.deletetask', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

This code above listens to the entire JS `document` object, which is not the most efficient use of resources, but it gets the job done. This method can be useful if the class `deletetask` is inserted in different places, and you want a single event listener to be able to handle the click events.

However, the **more efficient** way of doing this is to use the parent ID `tasksUL` (or a class would work too) that is already on the page from the start as your event listener like so:

```
$('#tasksUL').on('click', '.deletetask', function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

This section of code will listen to any click event inside of your ID `tasksUL` that happen on a class `deletetask`, and it only listens for those click events instead of listening for every single click event on the `document`.